# Confusion over the run time of 'Fireflies in the Garden'

Tags: alternate-version, fireflies-in-the-garden

Could someone please clear up the runtime confusion of this film?

I've seen it listed at 89 minutes, 94 minutes, 98 minutes, 99 minutes, and 120 minutes.

I watched it online for the first time and thought it was an excellent film. I don't remember the exact length of the version I watched, however. But I ordered the DVD, and upon watching it, I noticed right away that at least two scenes were significantly shortened. The runtime of my DVD is 89 minutes.

There doesn't appear to be a Blu-ray of the film available in the United States, only Canada and Europe... and I've been told that the European version of the film is the 120 minute one.

I know that, sometimes, European and American runtimes are often different. I've just never seen such confusion over the length of a film. I'd be happy with the standard U.S. edition, but due to the two scenes being shortened on my DVD, I believe I must have purchased yet another different variation of this movie...

If anyone has any info, I'd appreciate it.

For anyone wondering... The two scenes that have been cut are the scenes in which Ryne is sorting through her mother's clothing and flips out on Michael and Kelly... the other being where Kelly admits to Jane that she's pregnant while they're searching for Christopher. In fact, on my DVD we never even learn that Kelly is pregnant. They've cut that out entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0961108/technical) is usually the place to find such information.

> - 1 hr 39 min (99 min) (theatrical) (Germany)
> - 2 hr (120 min) (Berlin International) (Germany)
> - 1 hr 34 min (94 min) (DVD) (Australia)

There do appear to be other versions floating around. [This review](http://www.dvdverdict.com/reviews/firefliesingarden.php) (and [others](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0961108/reviews)) suggests that at least one DVD release was only 89 minutes long although the linked Amazon page lists the run time as being 120 minutes.

[Going by Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fireflies_in_the_Garden), *Fireflies in the Garden* was released in the US on October 14, 2011, which was close to four years after its European release on February 10, 2008 at the Berlin International Film Festival. The delay has been attributed to [significant editing and release issues](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/julia-roberts-fireflies-garden-finally-227963).

The reviews suggest that the shortened versions are too rushed and unsatisfactory.